# How is the sensor measurement treated in a Kalman filter?

Tags: kalman-filter

Consider the construction of a Kalman filter for estimating the attitude of an aircraft with IMU and a system dynamics in state space representation like this $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$

There are many papers focusing on this, some have treated angular velocity $\omega$ which can be measured by the IMU as an control input $u$. And the $\omega$ was used in the "predict" step of Kalman filter process.

The point that confused me is that the angular velocity measured by the IMU shouldn't be the "measurement" in the definition of the Kalman filter? And the control input $u$ shouldn't be the actuator such as aileron or elevator?